# LinearLayout Styling and XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I want to insert a new line in my layout. like In the first line i have 4 simple TextViews
and on the second line i want to have buttons .. 
Searching throw the internet i got answer like this:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when im looking at the a Desinger im getting all wigets on the same line
Where im a wrong  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this......

```
   <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <TextView
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
    <Button
      android:text="Text"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nope. Still the button is on the same line with the textView

Comment: Actually I don't under stand why the answer is not showing the root linear layout. Use a root linear layout of orientation vertical and inside of that linear layout add this code

Comment: try there http://pastebin.ru/319682 sorry the language is rus,but i dont know the services like that in American. there u can paste and edit the text we share

Comment: copy and paste the URL here, so i can take a look

Comment: THANK U VERY MUCH! IT HELPED! Finally i got the first andswer on this service!:D THANK U!

Answer (score 0):

where are your 4 textviews?

My advice is for create a new linearlayout with horizontal orientation and inside this put the 4 textview. Other solution is create a TableLayout and a TableRow.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Can you post a xml file with that? Im not sure of every thing i need to do